# os.system and writing to a file

Tags: python, c++, file-io

I've got a code to run simulation. To save time I have an other code in two part (one in python the other in C++) that will automatically launch my simulation code on the several node available taking into account the memory available etc.

In my simulation code I need to write a value into a file, at the last line. The goal is to write the result of the all the simulations one after the other in the abovementionned file. 
If I run "manually" my simulation code several time one after the other I get what I want, but when I use the code to do it automatically the results is written on the first line of the file thus deleting the previous result (or the file is deleted each time after the simulation).

I have first thought that a simultaneous access to the file from several instance of the simulation code might be the problem, but even with one simulation running at the time it doesn't work.

In the python code the command is send as os.system(my command).

Can someone help me ?

Thank you.

Edit: C++ command line to write in the file:

```
int SimJob::WriteValueToFile(std::basic_string<char> fileName, dcmplx *val)
{

   std::ofstream fsol(fileName.c_str(),std::ios::app);

   if (!fsol.is_open()) {
      std::cout << "Error opening output file: " << fileName << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
   fsol << std::scientific;
   fsol.precision(20);

      fsol <<*val <<" "<< lambda <<" "<< eps <<std::endl;

   fsol.close();
   return 0;
}
```

And the Python code eigen.py (not written by me)

```
import os.path
import os
import time
import sys

folder='/home/gbernasc/run/'+sys.argv[1]+'/'
randstring=sys.argv[2]
tempFolder='/tmp/gbernasc/'

n=int(sys.argv[3])
jobID=str(n)+'.xml'
solID=str(n)
os.chdir(folder)
print os.getcwd()
if(os.path.exists(jobID)):
    job=open(jobID,'r')
    jobScan=job.readlines()
    job.close()
    meshFile=jobScan[5]

    meshFile=meshFile.replace('\n','')
    tempFoldercur=tempFolder+randstring+'/'
    os.system('mkdir -p '+tempFolder)
    os.system('mkdir '+tempFoldercur)
    os.system('cp '+jobID+' '+tempFoldercur)
    os.system('cp '+meshFile+' '+tempFoldercur)
    #os.system('cp points '+tempFoldercur)
    os.chdir(tempFoldercur)
    logID=str(n)+'.log'

    os.system('SIENanoC -j '+ jobID) #+' > A'+logID)


    os.system('mv *sol '+folder)
    os.system('mv A'+logID+' '+folder)
    os.chdir(folder)
    os.system('rm -rf '+tempFoldercur)
```

And this code (eigen.py) is called in another C++ programme as:

```
 sprintf(launchjob,"screen -L -S %s -d -m python /home/gbernasc/bin/eigen.py %s %s %d",   simqueue.begin()->name,simqueue.begin()->dir,simqueue.begin()->name,simqueue.begin()->index);
```

Comment: Some more context is needed like 'where is it running' or 'where do you think is the problem'

Comment: OK. For me the problem come from the fact that I pass through the python code that use the command os.system("launch my job") to run my simulations, because if I write myself "launch my job" in the terminal it work. I use Putty for the terminal and the automatic launcher is a C++ code (that calls the python code). All of this on windows 7

Comment: Tell me if you need other information, I might not have enough knowledge on the subject to know what's really pertinent

Comment: I think you need to post writing to file part of code.